# How to run a TypeScript app compiled into a single file with AMD modules?

Tags: typescript, amd

*I'm sure I'm missing something completely trivial here, but for the life of it I can't figure it out. Only recently have I started using AMD (RequireJS). My app will (would) run in browsers.*

---

### Setup

In TypeScript 1.8, it's [possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#concatenate-amd-and-system-modules-with---outfile) to `tsc` an entire project composed of external modules into a single output file when using AMD.

For this reason, I finally decided to leave internal modules behind and make all of my VS2015 project `.ts` and `.tsx` files external modules, then compile them into a single file with the following compiler arguments:

```
--module AMD --outFile main.js
```

---

### Output

The *single* output main.js file is created as expected, listed in it are all modules which are part of the project:

**main.js**

```
define("Project/MainModule", ["require", "exports" ...], function (require, exports ...) {
    "use strict";
    console.log("MainModule defined");
    // ...
});

...
```

---

### Usage (?)

Now, how do I get `Project/MainModule` to run from -- for example -- index.html (so that it logs *"MainModule defined"* into console)? I have RequireJS loaded to handle the AMD syntax, as well as the main.js file specified for immediate loading:

**index.html**

```
<script data-main="main" src="Require.js"></script>
```

This correctly loads `main.js`, which I ensured by including a call to `console.log` after the huge list of defines in that file (outside modules). Pardon me if this is a trivial question, I couldn't find anything concerning how to *use* a compiled application with this approach (maybe I didn't use the right [keywords](https://www.google.hu/search?q=typescript+module+amd+outfile)?).

---

Edit: I tried requiring the module by its name:

**index.html**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        require(["Project/MainModule"], function () {
            // this
        });
    }
</script>
```

... but it's no good, RequireJS can't find the module.

Comment: I don't think you are doing this correctly.  You want to include main.js using a normal <script> tag AFTER you've loaded require.js using a normal <script> tag.  Then you can "require" them but they'll already be loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be loading the built file via a script tag:

```
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script src="built/run.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then you can load the modules using require:

```
<body>
    <script>require(["app"], run => run());</script>
</body>
```

The tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "out": "./built/run.js",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

See https://github.com/ca0v/ags-lab/blob/master/index.html for a dojo example.

See https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab/blob/master/rawgit.html for a requirejs example.

See https://github.com/ca0v/html-playground/blob/master/playground/svg/svgeditor/index.html for an almond example.

Alternatively, you can use data-main to load a requirejs configuration.  That configuration can specify the built script as a dependency.  For example:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "openlayers": "bower_components/ol3/ol",
        "jquery": "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min"
    },
    deps: ["built/run"],
    callback: () => {
        requirejs(["app"], run => run());
    }
});
```

And load this using data-main:

```
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="config.js"></script>
</head>
```

See https://github.com/ca0v/ol3-lab/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript compiler produces only `define` calls. To trigger module loading you need at least one top level `require` call.

When using RequireJS's `r.js` for bundling there is nice [option](https://github.com/requirejs/almond#triggering-module-execution-) for this reason.

Not sure how to use `--outFile` to achieve this. I believe you would need to use RequireJS API directly in `.ts` or `.js` in similar way you did in your **index.html**. Calling just `require(["Project/MainModule"]);` should be enough.

It there a reason why you don't want or can't use solution with [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#setup), [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/)?

Comment: _"It there a reason why you don't want or can't use solution with r.js, browserify or webpack?"_ I'd wish to keep my codebase independent from module loading implementation. This way I can compile the same codebase for `npm`, AMD, or ES6 syntax with just the flip of a switch.

Comment: Either way, it seems I'll need to add an additional build step. I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Of course. I assume you write modules in TypeScript syntax - then it is a setting for compiler/build tool to create runtime modules. All 3 supports this approach. For r.js you need to precompile the code base with ``tsc`` itself (the same way you do it now, just omit ``--outFile``) - additional build step. With webpack and browserify everything is done in memory stream - replaces ``tsc`` as build step.

Comment: If you mean the ES6 syntax: `import {SubComponent} from "Components/SubComponent"` -- yes, that's what I use.

Comment: Yes, in your codebase. Then just flip the switch for desired runtime module system - commonjs (npm), AMD (browser), ES6 (SystemJS or future)

Answer (score 2):

*This was indeed a trivial mistake -- for advanced RequireJS users.*

---

The module definitions created when compiling with AMD syntax and `--outFile` are named modules, [according to RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename).

To use a named module, it must be defined in RequireJS configuration by mapping the module name to the module path. In this case, we need to define that the named module `Project/MainModule` is in module (file) `main`:

**index.html**

```
<script>
    require.config({
        paths: {
            "Project/MainModule": "main"
        }
    });
</script>
```

And then require the module by its name, which can now be looked up from the file assigned to it:

**index.html**

```
<script>
    require(["Project/MainModule"], function () {
        console.log("app loaded");
    });
</script>
```

---

**Note**: the `data-main` attribute had to be omitted when including Require.js, or else the module would be loaded twice (or, at least the above example was logging twice).

**Note 2**: this is only part of the full solution. The `module -> file` mappings have to be specified for *all* modules emitted by the TypeScript compiler, which is not feasible at all. This related question has an applicable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36104345/2788872), however.

Comment: I believe that when you use relative module names ('./Project/MainModule') instead of named ('Project/MainModule') you would overcome the mappings issue.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This worked really well to get me going.

Answer (score 0):

I've written SAMD for this exact use case: https://github.com/morris/samd

It provides a minimal AMD implementation, sufficient for TypeScript AMD bundles and dependencies included via regular script tags.