# RequireJS paths config saying "all modules are in this file"

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In RequireJS, it's possible to configure paths explicitly for given modules. For example, you can specify that for module `foo` the module `bar` should be loaded instead (file `bar.js` should be loaded):

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
});
```

How can I do the same, but for *all* modules?

---

I tried using an asterisk, but it will only create a mapping for module `*` literally:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "*": "bar"
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not know the answer, but interested in the purposes that make you trying this... May I know what is it?

Comment: @LinhPham The TypeScript compiler is able to compile multiple external modules into named AMD modules placed into a single output file. However, to effectively _use_ those modules, RequireJS must be configured so that it knows where to find them.

Comment: very interesting. Do we have it like `jquery` + `underscore` => `define('jquery', [fucntion(){...}]);  define('underscore', [fucntion(){...}]);` into a single file? ---- if it is like this maybe a work-around can be applied.

Comment: @LinhPham Yes, precisely. Those are _named_ modules.

Comment: I got a work around for it. Not exactly what you expected but it will work in the same way. I will prepare an answer now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question and comment

> The TypeScript compiler is able to compile multiple external modules into named AMD modules placed into a single output file. However, to effectively use those modules, RequireJS must be configured so that it knows where to find them.

There is a work-around can be applied. First of all, let's not define any module paths in `config` except the path for all modules.

```js
require.config({
    paths: {
        "all": "path/to/all/modules"
    },
  
    deps: { "all" } // This to tell requireJS to load 'all' at initial state.
});
```

And then load the `config`/`main` file

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

From this requireJS will simply read all the `define()` blocks in `modules.js`. It will registering all the module names you got in the js file. For example if you got `define('myModule', [function(){...}]);` in your `module.js`. You can simply call to load it at any place without define a path for it.

For example some where in your code.

```
requirejs(['myModule', function(myModule){
    myModule.doSemething();
});
```

Comment: I'll have a look at in on Monday, but this seems like _the_ solution to my issue.